# How can I test latency or networking failures with Detox, can I simulate this with code?

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I'm trying to do a e2e test when there is no network connection. Is this possible with Detox even if it's simulated, if so, how?

I'm running e2e testing on my react native app for some libraries written in native code, the API calls are on the native library I just need to expect a networking error window to appear from the library.

I was thinking I could emulate latency somehow but I haven't managed to do it so far.

Comment: Not possible on Detox right now. You can swizzle the network request API that the native code performs and respond to those calls with an error.